# Refresh token faz requisição com atraso

Tags: angular, typescript

Como fazer o token ser criado na mesma hora que o metódo obterNovoToken for chamado:

Do jeito que eu implementei, ele verifica que o token foi criado, mas o token usado da requisição é o token expirado. Só depois que ele roda o método intercept, ele cria o novo token.

```
export class JwtInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const header = request.urlWithParams.indexOf('/oauth/token');
    let token = this.authService.getToken();

    console.log('TOKEN', token);

    if (header === -1 &&  this.authService.isAccessTokenInvalid()) {
      this.authService.obterNovoAccessToken();
      token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      console.log('NOVO TOKEN', token);
    }

    if (token && header === -1 && request.url.match(environment.apiUrl)) {
      const cloned = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      });
      return next.handle(cloned);
    } else {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
}
```

```
obterNovoAccessToken(): Promise<void> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      .append('Authorization', 'Basic YW5ndWxhcjpAbmd1bGFyMA==');

    const body = 'grant_type=refresh_token';

    return this.http.post<any>(this.oauthTokenUrl, body, { headers, withCredentials: true })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        this.armazenarToken(response.access_token);
        return Promise.resolve(null);
      })
      .catch(response => {
        return Promise.resolve(null);
      });
  }
```

Comment: O problema do seu codigo é que vc ta tratando algo assincrono de maneira sincrona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No meu caso eu sei que o token está expirado ou inválido só após eu realizar a requisição, então tive que tratar em um `catchError`, no meu caso usamos token rolante, então tenho que atualizar a cada requisição e mesmo quando o servidor envia algum erro eles me mandam um, então basta eu fazer a seguinte mudança.

```js
...
return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          const responseError = error as HttpErrorResponse;
          this.authService.token = error; // Aqui eu atualizo o meu token

          if (responseError.status === 401) {
            return this.error401(req, next, error);
          } else if (responseError.status === 403) {
            return this.error403(error);
          }
          return this.otherError(error);
        })
      );

...
```

Em meu token eu criei um `get` e um `set`, da seguinte forma

```js
  set token(data: any) {
    let token: string;

    if (data && data.headers && data.headers.get('x-access-token') && data.headers.get('x-access-token-type')) {
      token = `${data.headers.get('x-access-token-type')} ${data.headers.get('x-access-token')}`;
      localStorage.setItem(AuthService.TOKEN, token);
    }
  }

  get token() {
    return localStorage.getItem(AuthService.TOKEN);
  }
```

Porém acredito que você terá de tratar o seu token similar a forma que fiz com para tratar o `erro 401`. Algo como:

```js
error401(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return this.authService.refresh() // Sua função de renovar o token talvez fique aqui
      .pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.headerInterceptor.intercept(req, next)), // Eu separei em dois interceptors, um para tratar erros e outro apenas para editar o header
        catchError((refreshError) => {
          // Suas tratativas de erro aqui
        })
      );
  }
```